# remove 53 from work week time format in d3 (%V)

Tags: d3.js, time, plotly

I am using plotly with python and I need the work week format to be from 00 to 52.

But the `%V` format from [d3](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) is `[01, 53]`, in fact, 00 is represented by 53.

[image: tickers where 53 becomes 00 and appears before smaller numbers]

The time format in this image is `%V'%y`

I have tried using lower case `%v`, but it doesn't work.

This creates a weird sorting error of where `53'10` is before `05'10`. `53'10` should be `00'10`

How to use 00 instead of 53?

Is there a customized way of formatting the tickers from 00 to 52?

Comment: Are you familiar with ISO week-numbers?

Comment: Yes, that is the %V format, but I need the numbering to be from 00 to 52